# Zookeeper admin server Port

Tags: windows-10, apache-zookeeper

Installed zookeeper 3.5.6 bin on windows. Getting error:
Unable to start AdminServer, exiting abnormally
org.apache.zookeeper.server.admin.AdminServer$AdminServerException: Problem starting AdminServer on address 0.0.0.0, **port 8080** and command URL /commands

Where do I find the AdminServer configuration properties to fix this. In my conf directory the .cfg does not have anything, and I cant find anything anywhere else either?? [The documentation](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.5.1-alpha/zookeeperAdmin.html#sc_adminserver_config) is referring to zookeeper.admin.serverPort properties etc.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

By default, Admin Server binds to port 8080, in case port 8080 already in use this exception will be thrown.

Add below property to `conf/zoo.cfg` file and restart zk server.
`admin.serverPort=9876` (other port than 8080)

Or you could disable admin server altogether by
`admin.enableServer=false`

Comment: That easy- I will try and report. Somehow, as mentioned, the documentation does not say which file to put this config in. The zoo.cfg- has default values for everything, but not these. You think there is some other config file, but cant find.

Comment: I faced same problem as you, and solved by adding `admin.serverPort` property in `zoo.cfg` file only. You can also verify admin server running on given port in logs.

Comment: This works - the documentation has some confusion though.

Comment: `zkserver start` or stop don't work ?? Just using `zkserver` and `Ctrl-C`

Comment: This got me one time. I had another service running on port 8080. And ZK didn't start.

Comment: I was facing same issue and after adding `admin.serverPort=9876`  it has fixed my issue. Thank you so much !